# Python multiprocessing shared dict inside a class

Tags: python, dictionary, shared-memory

I want to understand how multiprocessing and manager works in order to shared memory

I have a class with a dictionary created on class.**init**
I want to use multiprocessing in order to call a class function which fill the dictionary (every process add a different key).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class num:
    def __init__(self):
        manager = Manager()
        d = manager.dict()

        # Setup list of processes
        processes = [mp.Process(target=self.f, args=(d,i)) for i in range(5)]

        #Run processes 
        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        #Exit the completed processes
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        print d

    def f(self,d,i):
        d[str(i)] = []
        d[str(i)].append(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':      
    test = num()
```

result:

```
{'1': [], '0': [], '3': [], '2': [], '4': []}
```

The list inside f() need to be shared too? How and why?

Comment: Question update after DNA answer in order to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the line in the function `f` from:

```
d['i'] = [i]
```

to something like

```
d[str(i)] = i
```

so that your processes don't overwrite one another's entries in the shared dict. After that, it works fine for me (in Python 2.7.3), printing out

```
{'1': 1, '0': 0, '3': 3, '2': 2, '4': 4}
```

(Also, the code you posted is missing an `import multiprocessing as mp`)

**Update**: if you just want the values in the shared dict to be lists, then that's a simple change, e.g.

```
d[str(i)] = [i]
```

If you want each of the lists to be shared across all the processes, then you probably need to create those lists in the main process, using `manager.list()`, and pass those to all the subprocesses, for example:

```
    count = 5
    lists = [manager.list() for i in range(count)]
    for i in range(count):
        d[i] = lists[i]
    processes = [mp.Process(target=self.f, args=(d,i, lists)) for i in range(count)]
```

[...]

```
def f(self,d,i, lists):
    for j in range(i):       # just an example to show 
        lists[j].append(i)   # that the lists are shared between processes
```

I also tried directly nesting the managed lists inside the managed dict, but for some reason this didn't work, and the subprocesses could not update the lists. Passing them separately as shown seems to work, e.g. I can get each subprocess to update multiple lists:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4], 4: []}
```

Comment: Thanks! I update the question to be more specific. I need the values of the dict to be lists - need to share the list memory too? how?

Answer (score 2):

replacing:

```
d[str(i)].append(i)
```

with:

```
d[str(i)] += [i]
```

solve the problem.

Result:

```
{'1': [1], '0': [0], '3': [3], '2': [2], '4': [4]}
```

But I realy want to know why.