# Shared dict of lists as values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a **multiprocessing** package.

I have a `manager = Manager()` and shared dict `self.graph = self.manager.dict()` and I want it to store integers as keys and lists of integers as values (adjacency list representation of graph), but when I try to append new element to list in worker process `graph` doesn't change at all.

So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294585/python-multiprocessing-shared-dict-inside-a-class) was mentioned replacing `graph[i].append(j)` with `graph[i] += [j]` makes it work.
But I don't know why.